# How to style WordPress posts when we use "wp:post-content"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am pretty new to WP dev. I am building a theme and was able to build my template, template parts and patterns pretty easily.

Now I am struggling with the style of the posts.

In my single post template I have:

```
<!-- wp:pattern {"slug":"theme_center/header"} /-->

<!-- wp:pattern {"slug":"theme_center/heroDarkTheme"} /-->

<!-- wp:group {"layout":{"type":"flex","flexWrap":"nowrap"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group main-content">
    <!-- wp:pattern {"slug":"theme_center/publishedAndShare"} /-->
    
    <!-- wp:group {"layout":{"type":"constrained"}, "tagName":"main" } -->
    <main class="wp-block-group col-6">
        <!-- wp:post-content /-->
    </main>
    <!-- /wp:group -->
        
    <!-- wp:pattern {"slug":"theme_center/researchTopics"} /-->
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->
    
<!-- wp:pattern {"slug":"theme_center/footer"} /-->
```

The problem for me is to understand how to style the content of the tag: `<!-- wp:post-content /-->`.

When I create a post, I just add content like titles, paragraphs, images...and everything is display on the frontend with the header, footer and other patterns.

But how can I style the different headers, paragraphs and images that the user adds in the post, as it's all under the magical tag 'wp:post-content' and I cannot target any html tags in it.

And I do not want to customize the elements with the UI during the post creation, I want that every time the user adds a paragraph, it has a stlye, when he adds an image, it has a certain size...

I hope that my question was clear enough.
Cheers

I did try to add a CPT but the result is the same as the same tag `<!-- wp:post-content /-->` is used :(

Comment: You add classes and ids to your content and using CSS to style it. wp:post-content just outputs what you build in backend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Snuffy but how can I target all h2 headers the user will add in his post, to add calsses and IDs? As for me as a dev, the content is magically inside 'wp:post-content'. I struggle to understand how that works. Maybe it's simple but I don't get it yet.

Comment: it was just example how to style different parts. For "default" h1,h2,h3 you just add css rules for them. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp . Each theme have style.css file which is used for that.  Here is the basics of making a theme - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/

Comment: It does not answer my question so I think I cannot explain my problem as precise I as would like to. English is not my mother tongue so maybe it's because of that. Thanks a lot anyway for your answer and your time @Snuffy :)